# How to change the border color of a single row in react-table

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, react-bootstrap, react-table

I know how to change the background color of a row in a `ReactTable` object (code below).

How do I change the color of the **border** of the row (not the border of the entire table)? I have tried replacing `background` in the below code to `border-color`, or `borderColor`, or `border`, and none of these options work - either, I get an error or nothing at all happens when it's compiled.

```
getTrProps={(state, rowInfo, column) => {
    if(rowInfo) {
        return {
            style: {
                background: "blue"
            }
        };
    }
    return {}; 
}
```

Comment: How is `getTrProps` in used? can you share more code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this:

```
getTrProps = (state, rowInfo, instance) => {
    if (rowInfo) {
      return {
        style: {
          border: rowInfo
            ? rowInfo.row.age >= 20
              ? "solid 1px black"
              : "none"
            : "none"
        }
      };
    }
    return {};
  };
```

Working Example:
https://codesandbox.io/s/react-table-gettrprops-ijgzy

Answer (score 0):

Follow this to change individual cell color based on row.value condition

```
{
  Header: () => <div className="text-center font-weight-bold">Status</div>,
  accessor: "selectedstatus",
  className: "font",
  width: 140,
  Cell: (row) => (
    <div
      className="text-center h-6"
      style={{ background: row.value === "Selected" ? "green" : "red" }}
    >
      {row.value}
    </div>
  ),
},
```